# "undefined local variable or method" in the rails console when it encounters methods provided by has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-console

My problem is when I try to use the rails console to update a user email I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'update_attribute'`

While working thru the problem I tried 
 `current_user = user.authrnticate(foobar)` and got back `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'user' for main:Object`

Which leads me to believe the "rails c" isn't using or seeing the **user.rb** file corectly.

I have tried restarting the rails server before and after performing [rake db:test:prepare] and [rake db:migrate].

My [rails c] will execute methods not defined in **user.rb**.

Rspec is running without a problem.  All tests in the user_spec are passing. and when I comment out `has_secure_password` all tests fail.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

before do 
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                      password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
end

subject { @user }

it { should respond_to(:name) }
it { should respond_to(:email) }
it { should respond_to(:password_digest) } 
it { should respond_to(:password) }
it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

it { should be_valid }

describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when name is to long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. 
                                        foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
        addresses.each do |invalid_address|
            @user.email = invalid_address
            @user.should_not be_valid
        end
    end
end

describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
        addresses.each do |valid_address|
            @user.email = valid_address
            @user.should be_valid
        end
    end
end

describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
        user_with_same_email = @user.dup
        user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
        user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when password doesn't match confirmation " do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "when password is too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5}
    it { should_not be_valid }
end

describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
        it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
        let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

        it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
        specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
end
end
```

My user.rb is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

[and here is the entire project on github](https://github.com/kpearson/kit_app)

I have looked exhaustively for a solution including a throe read of the ActiveRecord documentation and I'm stumped.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the helper methods are not available to be called in the console.

you can often access them by calling them via helper.helpername, but this doesn't always work

How are you getting the User from the database?

For example `user = User.find_by_name('name')`

Comment: Thats it! I didn't instantiate a variable user.  Thank you, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'user' for main:Object
```

Says that you didn't instantiate a variable user.

Did you fetch User from a database in to user variable?

Your irb session should look something like this:

To check if you have a user in database:

```
> User.all
```

If you have a valid user in database named "Jon"

```
> user = User.find_by_name("Jon")
> current_user = user.auhenticate("valid_password") #will work
```

If you don't have a user in  database:

```
> User.create(name: "Jon", email: "user@example.com",
                  password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
> user = User.find_by_name("Jon")
> current_user = user.auhenticate("valid_password") #will work
```

RSpec uses test database but rails c on default uses development one so make sure that you have a record in your development database when you want to work on it in rails c.

rails c command is loading all your project libraries.

Comment: Thats it! I didn't instantiate a variable user. Thank you so much!